# In WAMP, can you put different databases on different drives

Tags: mysql, wampserver

Right now all databases are in the default folder which is D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.21\data(different folders)

Is there a way to create a new database that would be on a different physical drive (lets say E:) (and keep all the other databases on D:) ?

The reason i am asking is that often drive speed seems to be the bottleneck. Thanks.

Comment: no, but you can look into https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/general-tablespaces.html

Comment: Its not controlled by WAMPServer its controlled by MySQL